# How to display higher-res thumbnails on Blogger

Tags: blogger

All this time I've been using `<img expr:src='data:post.thumbnailUrl'/>` to display thumbnails on my homepage, which outputs a 72x72 square image originally made for mobile browsing. I then use jquery to scale the image from 72-c to s300. I wonder if there's a different approach to get a thumbnail without using js.

The new set of templates released by Blogger can output a thumbnail size available in 32, 64, 128 and 256 px using data:post.featuredImage. How can I apply this to custom templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize the [resizeImage](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/4R_sAkgZH9I) operator to change image size without JavaScript. The code will look like -

```
<img expr:src='resizeImage(data:post.thumbnailUrl, 1600)'/>
```

> resizeImage(imageUrl, newSize, optionalRatio)
>
> The resizeImage operator takes 3 parameters:
>
> **imageUrl** - The original URL of the resizable image. 
> **newSize** - The new
>   width of the image 
> (optional) **ratio** - The integer ratio of width to
>   height for the resized image, e.g. “1:1” or “4:3”
>
> Notes
>
> If the imageUrl parameter is not a resizable image, the resizeImage
>   function will return the original imageUrl. 
> The ratio must be integer
>   numbers. 
> If the ratio is provided, the image will be cropped to those
>   exact dimensions.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!