# Which Blogger template data tag fetches original, unresized post image?

Tags: blogger, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, twitter-card

Blogger has a few layout data tags used to fetch post images, such as `data:blog.postImageUrl` (which fetches the URL of the first image in your post) and `data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl` (which generates a 70×70 px thumbnail of the first image in your post, which is too small to use when sharing on Facebook/Twitter/etc.).

However, when publishing a post, Blogger will automatically use the first image in your post to generate its own `og:image` meta tag using a specially resized and/or cropped version of your image. Importantly, this generated image will ignore any custom resizing or cropping you may have done to the post image by modifying the `s1600` in its URL ([explained here](https://sneeit.com/using-blogger-blogspot-image-url-structure-for-cropping-and-resizing/)), returning a large-size image that’s perfect for sharing on social media sites. (It even crops the image down to a 1.91:1 ratio, as recommended in Facebook’s “[Best Practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images)”.)

Here’s an example:

Original image URL (size: 600×450:)
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-rEPYMMK3vT0/WaVHqLSY7-I/AAAAAAAAA2A/CVMWqg18oU8HEIyo3r3CWrcO8Bm7O4uiwCLcBGAs/s1600/Montreal-Biodome-exterior.jpg

Resized image using custom size value of `w180` (for a maximum width of 180 px):
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-rEPYMMK3vT0/WaVHqLSY7-I/AAAAAAAAA2A/CVMWqg18oU8HEIyo3r3CWrcO8Bm7O4uiwCLcBGAs/w180/Montreal-Biodome-exterior.jpg

And here’s the image that Blogger automatically generates (cropped to 600×315):
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-rEPYMMK3vT0/WaVHqLSY7-I/AAAAAAAAA2A/CVMWqg18oU8HEIyo3r3CWrcO8Bm7O4uiwCLcBGAs/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/Montreal-Biodome-exterior.jpg

Note how the auto-generated image uses its own size value of `w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu`, completely ignoring the `w180` I specified.

---

The problem for me is that I also use Twitter’s “Summary Card with Large Image”. I try to specify what image URL to use for the `twitter:image` card meta tag using Blogger data tags, like so:

```html
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' name='twitter:image'/>
OR
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' name='twitter:image'/>
```

Except that the first (`postImageThumbnailUrl`), as mentioned at the top, is far too small at 70×70 px, whilst the second (`data:blog.postImageUrl`) fetches the image URL with the customized size value of `w180`, returning an image only 180 px wide – just as useless for sharing on Twitter (the resulting Twitter Card uses a blank placeholder image).

What I’ve done for now is to remove the `twitter:image` tag altogether, which forces Twitter to use the `og:image` tag so that link sharing works. However, I’d prefer to use the `twitter:image` tag with the right image data tag if at all possible.

**So this is my question:** Does anyone know what the data tag is, if one exists, to fetch the large, cropped `w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu` version of a post image that Blogger generates for each post? Like so:

```html
<meta expr:content='data.{ETC}' name='twitter:image'/>
```

Which, in a post using the above image, would render as:

```html
<meta content='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-rEPYMMK3vT0/WaVHqLSY7-I/AAAAAAAAA2A/CVMWqg18oU8HEIyo3r3CWrcO8Bm7O4uiwCLcBGAs/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/Montreal-Biodome-exterior.jpg' name='twitter:image'/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display higher-res thumbnails on Blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500573/how-to-display-higher-res-thumbnails-on-blogger)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that question; I hadn’t seen it in my searching. I’ll check it out later today when I have more time and test the solution it offers to see if it matches my problem.

Comment: @PrayagVerma I tried it out and it works perfectly (once I stopped typo’ing it up). Problem solved; I’ve posted the solution with the working code below. Thanks. EDIT: Also, I can’t seem to resolve the “duplicate question” issue with this question. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thanks to [Prayag Verma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940988/which-blogger-template-data-tag-fetches-original-unresized-post-image#comment78852916_45940988) for pointing to a [similar existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500573/how-to-display-higher-res-thumbnails-on-blogger) that answered this one. Using the [`resizeImage` operator](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/4R_sAkgZH9I), I implemented the following code to my template:

```html
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageUrl'>
  <meta expr:content='resizeImage(data:blog.postImageUrl, 1200, "40:21")' name='twitter:image'/>
</b:if>
```

Which, in the post’s source, renders as:

```html
<meta content='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-rEPYMMK3vT0/WaVHqLSY7-I/AAAAAAAAA2A/CVMWqg18oU8HEIyo3r3CWrcO8Bm7O4uiwCLcBGAs/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/Montreal-Biodome-exterior.jpg' name='twitter:image'/>
```

That’s exactly what I was trying to get. It passes the Twitter Validator with flying colors. Problem solved.